# Observable Command and Unit tests with Rx RTM

Tags: windows-runtime, system.reactive, reactiveui

I have ported my code to the RTM version of both WinRT and Rx. I use ReactiveUI in my ViewModels. Before porting the code my unit tests were running without problem but now I got a strange behavior.

Here the test:

```
var sut = new MyViewModel();
myViewModel.MyCommand.Execute(null) //ReactiveAsyncCommand
Assert.AreEqaul(0, sut.Collection.Count)
```

If I debug the test step by step, the assertion is **not** failing, but using the test runner it's failing...

The Collection asserted is modified by a method subscribing to the command:

```
MyCommand.RegisterAsyncTask(_ => DoWork())
            .ObserveOn(SynchronizationContext.Current)
            .Subscribe(MethodModifyingCollection);
```

The code was working before moving it to the RTM. I tried also to remove the `ObserveOn` and add an `await Task.Delay()` before the Assert without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Steven's got the rightish answer, but there are a few RxUI specific things missing. This is definitely related to scheduling in a test runner, but the reason is that the WinRT version of ReactiveUI can't detect properly whether it's in a test runner at the moment.

The dumb workaround for now is to set this at the top of all your tests:

```
RxApp.DeferredScheduler = Scheduler.CurrentThread;
```

Do **not** use the TestScheduler for every test, it's overkill and actually isn't compatible with certain kinds of testing. TestScheduler is good for tests where you're simulating time passing.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that MSTest unit tests have a default `SynchronizationContext`. So `ObserveOn` and `ReactiveAsyncCommand` will marshal to the thread pool instead of to the WPF context. This causes a race condition.

Your first and best option is the [Rx `TestScheduler`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh242967%28v=VS.103%29.aspx).

Another option is to `await` some completion signal (and ensure your test method is `async Task`, not `async void`).

Otherwise, if you just need a `SynchronizationContext`, you can use [`AsyncContext` from my AsyncEx library](http://nitoasyncex.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=AsyncContext) to execute the tests within your own `SynchronizationContext`.

Finally, if you have any code that directly uses `Dispatcher` instead of `SynchronizationContext`, you can use `WpfContext` from the Async CTP download.

Comment: Thank Stephen for the answer. I'm going to test it tomorrow but I'm on WinRT so the WPF-related solutions are not an option. TestScheduler seems promising.

Comment: `WpfContext` - despite the name - just uses `Dispatcher` and I believe works for SL, so I expect it would work for WinRT as well.